# Show that its inverse, denoted by $h^{-1}$, is also a strictly increasing function.

Tags: calculus

Let h be a strictly increasing continuous function. Show that its inverse, denoted by $h^{-1}$, is also a strictly increasing function.

How to approach this question?

Comment: How is this related to probability?

Comment: Just use the definition of a strictly increasing function. Write down what it means that $h$ is strictly increasing. Then write down what you want to prove, i.e. $h^{-1}$ being strictly increasing. Then you should see that the latter follows from the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $x<y$ (in co-domain of $h$) and $h^{-1}(x)\geq h^{-1}(y)$, then by applying $h$ (increasing) we get $h(h^{-1}(x)) = x\geq h(h^{-1}(y))=y$, contradiction. (No need for continuity etc.)

Comment: still do not quite get it...could you flush out a little more...why $h^{-1}(x) \ge h^{-1} (y)$? and why applying h (strictly increasing) we get $h(h^{-1}(x)) = x \ge h(h^{-1}(y)) = y$?

Comment: Let $x<y$. We want to prove that $h^{-1}(x) < h^{-1}(y)$. We will do this by contradiction. So, lets assume $h^{-1}(x) \geq h^{-1}(y)$. As $h$ is strictly increasing, then $h(h^{-1}(x)) \geq h(h^{-1}(y))$. This is equivalent to $x\geq y$, contradicting our starting given inequality $x<y$.

Comment: what if h(x) and h(y) are zeros?

Comment: $h(x)$ and $h(y)$ don't play any role here; remember that $x$ and $y$ belong to the co-domain (image) of $h$, so $h$ can't act on them. The only way $h$ is used is by its property $h(h^{-1}(z)) = z$ for all $z$ (in its image) and by its property of being strictly increasing: if $a<b$ in its domain, then $h(a) < h(b)$ (note that if $a=b$, then obviously $h(a)=h(b)$, just by the fact that $h$ is a function).

Comment: what is the relationship between $x < y$ and $h^{-1} (x) \geq h^{-1} (y)$? If so, how do you know that relationship? My understanding for this relationship is I think of x and y as numbers. However, if x = any negative number and y = positive number, then $x < y$ and $h^{-1} (x) \leq h^{-1} (y)$ ... if x or y = 0 , the inverse does not even exist....correct me if I am wrong

Comment: In our reasoning, $x<y$ is GIVEN. ASSUMING $h^{-1}(x) \geq h^{-1}(y)$ leads to a contradiction (via $h$ and its two properties I mentioned).

Comment: I know $h^{-1} (x) \geq h^{-1} (y)$ is your assumption...However, how do you know this is true given that we take $x < y$ for granted

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12806/discussion-between-ir7-and-afsdf-dfsaf)